# CLOSED reading multiple condition of if statement

Tags: vba

im trying to make all the statements are readable, and the program should read each condition. This is a mistake i somehow realized it because im using if else of course it will not go through each conditions. but im stuck because i don't know how to solve this problem

```
 'I want to state two condition (A) and (B) thats why I am using IF and 
 'ELSE. but inside (B) i want to pass through first, second, and third 
 'condition

    '(A)

    If tmpRS2.EOF Then 
        tmpRS2.AddNew
        tmpRS2.Fields("ADPS_CD").Value = KOM_04
        tmpRS2.Fields("ADPS_NAME").Value = KOM_14 & KOM_05 & KOM_06
        tmpRS2.Update
        YC = YC + 1

    ' (B) The problem starts here ---->               

    Else  'it will not go through each one of the condition, 

          'first condition

         If KOM_14 & KOM_05 & KOM_06 <> tmpRS2.Fields("ADPS_NAME").Value Then  
            tmpRS2.DbEdit
            tmpRS2.Fields("ADPS_NAME").Value = KOM_14 & KOM_05 & KOM_06
            tmpRS2.Update
            UC = UC + 1

         Else
             'second condition

             If KOM_14 & KOM_05 & KOM_06 <> tmpRS2.Fields("SCT_NAME").Value Then 
                tmpRS2.DbEdit 
                tmpRS2.Fields("SCT_NAME").Value = KOM_14 & KOM_05 & KOM_06
                tmpRS2.Update
                UC = UC + 1
             Else

                     'third condition

                     If KOM_14 & KOM_05 & KOM_06 <> tmpRS2.Fields("DIV_NAME").Value Then 
                        tmpRS2.DbEdit
                        tmpRS2.Fields("DIV_NAME").Value = KOM_14 & KOM_05 & KOM_06
                        tmpRS2.Update
                        UC = UC + 1
                     End If
         End If

    End If
```

Comment: What if you write your if next to each other and remove the else's? (If...End If - If...End If ...)

Comment: @Damien read my question again, i need to fulfill If (A) else (B) cannot use if and end if only. have to use else.

Comment: @Damien is right. Since you check all three conditions separately, just put  your three `If KOM_14 & KOM_05 & ... Then ...  End If` into section (B) between `Else ... End if`. No need for further nesting.

Comment: @MartinDreher i see. now i see what Damien tried to say. cool, got that. sounds good!

Comment: @Damien thanks! ;D peacee!

Answer (score 0):

use ElseIf:

```
If tmpRS2.EOF Then 
      '.....
ElseIf KOM_14 & KOM_05 & KOM_06 <> tmpRS2.Fields("ADPS_NAME").Value Then
      '.....
ElseIf KOM_14 & KOM_05 & KOM_06 <> tmpRS2.Fields("SCT_NAME").Value Then
      '.....
ElseIf KOM_14 & KOM_05 & KOM_06 <> tmpRS2.Fields("DIV_NAME").Value Then
      '.....
End If
```

Comment: using elseif means 'either one' for example if ADPS_NAME fulfill the condition, it will skip to END IF. it will not read through the SCT_NAME and DIV_NAME